# Search for a module in all Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, module, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Is it somehow possible so search for a module within all Jenkins jobs?

Let's say there's the module *common-messaging*. It's built in *Job 1* and *Job 2*.

When I search for the module name I want both jobs to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins store the jobs configuration on disk in XML files. So you can grep the file for whatever XML element is created by the plugin.

- create a new job that just have that plugin enabled.
- get the XML file:  /ci/job/name_of_your_job/config.xml
- look for an XML element that correspond to common-messaging, lets say common-messaging.plugin

Then if using a UNIX system:

```
grep common-messaging.plugin /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/*/config.xml
```

Windows must have a similar command.

Answer (score 2):

If you have admin access to the server, install the [Scriptler plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scriptler+Plugin) (which gives you more easy access to the Groovy console), and fetch and run this shared Scriptler snippet: http://scriptlerweb.appspot.com/script/show/486001

Comment: For reference purpouses use archived Version https://web.archive.org/web/20150516115604/http://scriptlerweb.appspot.com/script/show/486001 on archive.org